# Use get_text() for only one HTML class - Python, BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to access the only text in one class HTML. I tried to apply to the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) BeautifulSoup, but I always get the same error message or all items in this tag.

**My code.py**

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "https://www.auchandirect.pl/auchan-warszawa/pl/pepsi-cola-max-niskokaloryczny-napoj-gazowany-o-smaku-cola/p-98502176"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'}, timeout=15)
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
type(soup)

products_links = soup.findAll("a", {'class' : 'current-page'})

print(products_links)
```

In the results i only needs this 'Max niskokaloryczny napój gazowany o smaku cola'.

My results are:

```
<a class="current-page" href="/auchan-warszawa/pl/pepsi-cola-max-niskokaloryczny-napoj-gazowany-o-smaku-cola/p-98502176"><span>Max niskokaloryczny napój gazowany o smaku cola</span></a>
```

Or if i will apply this code according to the documentation (print(products_links.get_text())) Pycharm returns:

```
ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?"
```

How can I extract the text correctly from "current-page"?
Why does not the function return text in the tags ?
What's the difference in getting access to a class using 'findAll("a", class_="current-page")' relative to 'findAll("a", {'class' : 'current-page'})'it gives the same results?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

findAll returns a list of items found in your defined tag. Imagine if there are multiple tags alike, it returns a list of the multiple tags that match.

There should not be any differences whether you use `findAll("a", class_="current-page")` or passing a dict with multiple arguments `{'class' : 'current-page'}`. I might be wrong but I believe because some of these methods were inheritted from earlier versions.

You can extract a text from the returned object by selecting the element and getting the text attribute shown below:

```
products_links = soup.findAll("a", {'class' : 'current-page'}, text = True)
print(products_links[0].text)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
Maybe it's because of my poor knowledge of English, but where in the documentation I can find this information? how did you know to use 'text = True' and to products_links '.text' elements?
Is it possible to explain it sensibly?

Comment: No problem. Hope it helped. You should be able to get the info here, https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs). I do not think `text = True` is required, what is important is that you know that `findAll` returns a list of objects that match your parameters.